# How is outgoing transactions scanned?

Tags: wallet, balance

Almost every info about decoding outputs of txs are about ingoing transactions that you can see with only private view key, how is outgoing transactions scanned? Which calculations are made to verify an outgoing transaction? For example I have only my seed (so private spend and view key too), and I want to calculate my current balance. I can calculate my ingoing transactions with private view key, but how can I calculate my outgoing transactions so I can truly find my balance? Don't forget that I don't know anything else other than my private keys and blockchain data, I am restoring a wallet from scratch.